# Filter based on mutually related models

Tags: django, python-2.7

I have Three models

```
class Song(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    bandname = models.ManyToManyField(Band)
    albumname = models.ManyToManyField(Album)

class Band(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Album(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

Now I wants to list all albums for a particular band.

I've tried this way, in view.py

```
band = Band.objects.get(id=no)
song_list = band.song_set.all()
album = [i.bandname for i in song_list]
```

It's not working. Please help me.

Comment: Are you sure your models are right? How can a song be by more than one band?

Comment: a duet song, may be. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems what you're actually trying to get is a list of all the albums that contain songs by a particular band, either exclusively or in duet. Here's how you could get that using your existing models:

```
band = Band.objects.get(id=target_band_id)
song_list = Song.objects.filter(bandname=band)
album_list = Album.objects.filter(song__in=song_list).distinct()
```

Check "Reverse m2m queries" within [the Django Many to Many docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/).

I would also suggest re-naming `bandname` and `albumname` to simply `band` and `album` because they are referring to band or album model instances, not the actual names of the band or album. That would get confusing later on if you wanted to add a `name` field to either the `Band` or `Album` models.

Comment: it gives the error
    Cannot resolve keyword 'song_set' into field. Choices are: id, title, song

so I tried

album_list = Album.objects.filter(song__in=song_list).distinct()


It worked. Thank You.